# Mockito.doAnswer vs ArgumentCaptor in Unit Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I am new in `Unit Testing` in `Java` and tried to test a void method using `ArgumentCaptor`. On the other hand, I have seen that there is another approach called `Mockito.doAnswer` that can also be used for testing a `void` method.

In this scene:

**1.** What are the main purposes of `Mockito.doAnswer` and `ArgumentCaptor`?

**2.** What are the differences between `Mockito.doAnswer` and `ArgumentCaptor` and pros/cons of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're completely different things.

- `DoAnswer` is for stubbing.  For setting up "fake" behaviour that you want to have occurring when a particular method is called.
- `ArgumentCaptor` is for verification.  You use it if you want to check what arguments were passed to a method, during the running of a test.

Comment: Thanks for reply, voted up. Whats is stubbing actually in testing?

Comment: I literally answered that in my first bullet point.  _Stubbing_ is  setting up fake behaviour that you want to have occurring when a particular method is called.

Comment: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/stubbing-and-mocking-with-mockito-2-and-junit

Comment: On the other hand, do I need to use `DoAnswer` if I can perform the same thing with `Mockito.when`?